# crop portrait image and resize to make a landscape cover css

Tags: html, css, background-image

I have an image like this
[image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/l7pP3.jpg)

Using HTML and CSS, how can I crop the middle part of the image and turn it into a landscape cover background like the picture below:

[pic](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ajaAI.jpg)

The background should be 100% width and height about 400-500px at full screen and responsive. An addition of how to make the search box would be great. Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

This CSS should do it:

```
.container {
  height: 100vh; 
  background-color: #e3e3e3;
  display: flex; 
  align-items: center;
}
.image {
  width: 100%; height: 200px; background-color: white;
  background: url(https://i.stack.imgur.com/l7pP3.jpg) center center;
  background-size: cover;
}
```

Here's a sample: https://jsfiddle.net/7ka9jbhg/3/

Comment: somehow it can only cover 2/3 of my screen width in this case.